# getting all html attributes in an array

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I'm wondering if there any way to get all html attributes and put them in an Javascript array , I meen all html attributes that can be set to HTML elements including global attributes

Comment: You mean all attributes that exist on an element, or all attributes that hypothetically *could* exist on an element?

Comment: all attributes that hypothetically could exist on an element

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic process that will give you that list, no. You'll need to get that information [from the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) and maintain your own array, keeping it up to date as the specification evolves. [The index](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1) provides a handy reference for them, and references the [list of globals](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes) as well. And you'll want to allow for the fact that any element can have any number of [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).